# complex arguments for function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

My task is to create function funCall taking four arguments :

- pointer for 2d array of ints that stores pairs of numbers
- variable int maintaining number of numbers in 2d array
- pointer for table of pointers to functions
- int variable storing info about number of pointers to functions

I was thinking about something like this :

```
typedef int(*funPtr)(int, int);
funPtr arrayOfFuncPtrs[];

void funCall( *int[][]k, int a, *funPtr z, int b);
{
}
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: I don't suppose `funPtr` takes an "integer" in the complex plane.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  That might inform how you lay out your code and data structures.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef int(*funPtr)(int, int);

void funCall( int** array_2d, int num_of_nums, funPtr* fn_ptr_array, num_of_fn_ptrs)
{
}
```

like this?

Comment: `int array_2d[][2]` would be better.